# How to make screen flashing/blinking from background service on Android device?

Tags: android, android-layout

I plan to do background service which will make screen flashing/blinking until user touches screen.

I do not know methods how to make screen flashing - only what learned that could be done with brightness and control via spawned activity.

Want to do flashing with color change on screen i.e. black and white or screen on/off to make it more visible than wih brightness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your Service you can interact with the `WakeLock`:

Acquire the `WakeLock` with:

```
PowerManager powerMan = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerMan.newWakeLock(
                     PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | 
                     PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "wakelockTag");
```

Then to turn the screen on:

```
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Then to turn it off again:

```
wakeLock.release();
```

And you could put this into a `Thread` with a sleep or use a `Timer` to create the flash.

For example:

```
new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                boolean screenOn = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    try {
                        sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (screenOn) {
                        wakeLock.acquire();
                    } else {
                        wakeLock.release();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.run();
```

It wouldn't be black/white, just on/off.

If you wanted to go black/white you would have to also disengage the `KeyLock` (Look up the **Android Keyguard**), and then push an `Activity` that was completely Black, then change the `Activity` to White on a `Timer` or in a `Thread` as before. Much more work.

Remember to get permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Additional permissions will be required for unlocking the `KeyGuard` if you go down that route.

Answer (score 13):

I used this for screen blinking, In this code my relativeLayout (HomeLayout) will blinking.

```
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha
// from fully
// visible to
// invisible
animation.setDuration(500); // duration - half a second
animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // do not alter
// animation
// rate
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // Repeat animation
// infinitely
animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // Reverse animation at

// the
// end so the layout will
// fade back in
relativeLayout.startAnimation(animation);
```

Add this code, when you touch the scree or button to clear the animation.

```
relativeLayout.clearAnimation();
```

Comment: I will test soon - is it works as overlay mean that some background service could call it to show in frontend?

Comment: @Chameleon: i won't call any back ground services at this time, i did to play a tone when the screen is blinking. so change this code as your wish. :)

Comment: Mean rather that if it possible to control screen blinking from background service - not know if it possible :)

Comment: @Chameleon: Sorry i didn't know about that. In my case this will enough that's why i can't go for that.

Comment: @Aerrow sorry but.. after typing your code my eclipse can't resolve the relative layout, can you please help me out?

Comment: @We'reAllMadHere: Here relativelayout is parent layout id of you current view, for example : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"

Comment: @Aerrow, thanks for this, but getting an error when i try to call my relative layout id in: `relativeLayout.startAnimation(animation);`. i have never seen use of a layout without first a line like this `RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.flashLayout);` first. but i try to put in that line and the `Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);` has an error: "Unreachable statement". any idea why this is?

Comment: I want to stop animation..how can i do? i used a button to stop and start but animation starts only for a few second..if(flag==false)
  {
  rl.clearAnimation();
  flag=true;
  }
  else
  {
   animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
   rl.startAnimation(animation);
   flag=false;
  }