# How to make screen backlight on/off like blinking during period of time in Android?

Tags: android, screen, light

Is it possible to make the screen backlight of device turn on and off during e.g 30 seconds so that it looks like a blinking screen?

```
public class blinking extends TimerTask {
@Override
public void run() {
    PowerManager powerMan = (PowerManager) *getSystemService*(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerMan.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK |
                    PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "wakelockTag");

    boolean screenOn = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        if (screenOn) {
            wakeLock.acquire();
            screenOn = false;
        } else {
            wakeLock.release();
            screenOn = true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

And use this code in my Activity class (for calling Blinking class):

```
Timer mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.schedule( new blinking(), 30000 );
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14651018/4224337 ?

Comment: I think the part of powerManger is my answer.but how can I use this code with Timer? (just the first part of answer, before Thread part, I mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your class:

Create the power managr parameter

```
PowerManager powerMan = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerMan.newWakeLock(
                     PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | 
                     PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "wakelockTag");
```

Call the timer

```
Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.schedule( new FlashingTimerTask(), 30000 );
```

And for the Timer task:

```
public class FlashingTimerTask extends TimerTask{

    @Override
    public void run() {
            boolean screenOn = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                if (screenOn) {
                    wakeLock.acquire();
                    screenOn = false;
                } else {
                    wakeLock.release();
                    screenOn = true;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. i use this code but there is problem in "getSystemService". this function is not recognize for Intelij. what can i do?

Comment: public class blinking extends TimerTask {
    private Context context;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        PowerManager powerMan = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerMan.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK |
                        PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "wakelockTag");
... (the code you suggest me)
        }}}

Comment: are you using this code inside an activity? if no, try getActivity().getSystemService....

Comment: i use this code TimerTask class(you have said). in your code, i didn't what is "wakeLock"?! so i search it and found "PowerManager" code.

Comment: and also,"getActivity()" is not recognized?!. what should i do?

Comment: Yeah you must create *wakeLock* from *PowerManager* as the link abouve.
Post your class code(where you are using this code), to help you to figure out the problem.

Comment: i use your code at all, but i post codes. as i wrote before, "getActivity().getSystemService..." is not recognized.

Comment: of course i use this permission "    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
"too.

Comment: You should create powerMan and wakeLock variables inside the class (the activity) from where you call *blinking* not inside the Task. You can define powerMan and wakeLock as class variables and declare *blinking* as subclass to your activity or simply pass the *wakeLock* variable as parameter to your Task.